# change direction of nativescript slider

Tags: slider, nativescript, right-to-left, nativescript-angular

is there a way to make the native script slider RTL?

I want it to move from right to left like this pic
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For you case, you could use Slider `rotate` property. For Example:

```
<StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Slider rotate="180" loaded="slloaded" minValue="0" maxValue="100" value="" />
    </StackLayout>
```